# App42 Custom Code Instantiating Mechanism

Tags: java, custom-code, app42

I'm using App42 Custom-Code feature, I want to know how objects are instantiated, i.e. is there a single instance of my class that implements `Executer` and the function `execute` is called for every request, or a new instance is instantiated for every request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When request arrives at server, new instance  is created for that request and execute method is called on the same. Also, Executor class get unloaded after processing your request.